# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate for creating rest api

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to create a get rest api, i am using wampp server to test this file and under www folder have cacert.perm on the same directory. The problem i am now getting ssl certificate problem and cant seem to solve this issue and need some help.

```
<?php

// Set up the request URL and headers
$url = 'https://www.axxess.co.za/careers/dev-test';
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('applicant:canCode'),
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Set up the request body with the specified fields and values
$data = array(
    'first_name' => 'James',
    'last_name' => 'Nelson',
    'mobile_number' => '0739950802',
    'email_address' => 'jackson@gmail.com'
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

// Initialize a cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Execute the request and store the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: The answer is found here: https://thisinterestsme.com/php-curl-ssl-certificate-error/

Comment: @HonkderHase thanks it made the error fixed.